# Position: Fixed or Resizable but not both

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML element that I need to say in the bottom left corner of the screen, so I gave it:

```
position:fixed;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
```

I would also like to be able to make the element taller, so that it will stretch from the bottom to any height. The problem is when I have it as `position:fixed;` jQuery's `resizeable()` handle will cause it to jump as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721706/jquery-resize-causes-jump) question. The solution there was to change the position to absolute, but now the problem is that the element is no longer fixed to the bottom of the window. How can I have both?

[JSFiddle: Resize Yes, Fixed Position No](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/wzFCm/)

[JSFiddle: Resize Yes, Fixed Position Yes, Jumping Yes](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/v2dPj/)

Comment: Can you post a demo of your problem? Some html and the javascript you have so far

Comment: if that is not working then writing the code on your own using javascript/jquery is better option I suppose.

Comment: @Mathias I've added two fiddles The first isn't fixed, the second jumps

Comment: @Markasoftware do you have a javascript solution to this?

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem, because I've never used jQuery very much and don't really know what the `resizeable()` function does

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position: absolute` the element will take as a reference the parent element. So if the element you want to place is inside a `div` with an specific size, it will not go outside this `div`.

Try putting this element you want to stay fixed as a child of the `body` tag.

**EDIT:**

But anyway, if you scroll the page the element will not stay fixed (if that's what you want)

Comment: I just added the fiddles that show how it works, it already is a child of the body.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to use position absolute and then do something like

```
$.fn.set_bottom = function(div){  
   var h = $(window).height();
   var elem_h = $("#"+div).height();
   var et = h - elem_h;
   $("#"+div).css("top" , et+"px");
};

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(this).set_bottom("bottom-div");
   $(window).resize(function(){
     $(this).set_bottom("bottom-div");
  });
});
```

Probably not the best solution. But will work.

Comment: Will this keep the menu at the bottom, even after I scroll?

Comment: yes.. it will as it is positioned absolute. But u need to put this code under $(window).resize() event for best result. Let me edit my ans